# Convert each character of string into integer

Tags: android, string

I have hard coded 'a to z' integers with their respective integer/number values.
like

```
    int a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, f=5, g=6;
```

Now i have an edit text which can take input like abcdefg. I want to convert each character of string into int so that i can get
0123456 in return of abcdefg
Is that possible? please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: C or Java? In C, this is fairly simple...

Comment: I am using java. yes it is simple in C through ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this its better to use hashmap

delecare values in hash map as like below

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    map.put("a", 0);
    map.put("b", 1);
    map.put("c", 2);
    map.put("d", 3);
            //....
    map.put("z",25);


    String s1 ="abcdefg";//String from edit text
    char[] sa = s1.toCharArray();//converting to character array.
    String str ="";
    for(int i=0;i<sa.length;i++)
    {
        str = str+(map.get(Character.toString(sa[i])));
    }
    System.out.println(str);//Here str show the exact result what you required.
```

Comment: This is exactly what my question is. but i think i was vague about my question.I explicitly want 0 1 2 3 4 in integer variable of name a b c d e f  respectively. coz i want to use that integer variables in some computation. Like in EditText a is entered the value of a is 0 in the code. i want to do  with 'a'  is(0+3)% 26 the answer is 3 i research the map set found 3 in 'd' then i print d. you got the logic?? Kindly help me if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple . First you have to get string from edittext then convert it to string array and in for loop compare it.

```
String convertedText;
String str = editText.getText().toString();;
char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
for (char c : ch)
{
      System.out.println(c);
      if(c == 'a')
          convertedText = convertedText + "1"; 
      // Coding to compare each character
}
```

Comment: It seems logical but i Cannot invoke equals to char. c=="a"also didn't work. There is a suggestion to convert C into string. How can i compare char?

Comment: @dan use '' single quote. c == 'a'

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to modify the input in the edit text, i.e. when the user inters 'a' he see '1' instead..Try overriding `addTextChangedListener` use `onTextChanged` (if you want to modify it while the user is writing) or `afterTextChanged` (if you want to modify it after the user is done):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
    }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done like this
ASCI value of a is  97 to get the value 0 subtract 97 so..

IN C

```
.......
char *insert = "abcdefg";
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
int value = ((digit_to_int(insert[i]))-97)+1
printf("%d", value );
.........



int digit_to_int(char d)
{
 char str[2];

 str[0] = tolower(d);
 str[1] = '\0';
 return (int) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
}
```

you can attain this

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
String text = "hitesh";
    char[] ch = text.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char cd :ch)
    {
        int n = cd-'a'; 
        sb.append(n);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```